# Separable nonassociative algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra, non-associative-algebras, separable-algebras

In his paper *"[Structure and Representation of Nonassociative Algebras](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ebrusso/SchaferBAMS1955.pdf)"*, Schafer notes that an arbitrary nonassociative algebra over a field is separable "if and only if the multiplication centers of its simple summands are separable fields" (over the center of the algebra). This definition is very similar to one of the equivalent conditions for arbitrary *associative* algebras to be separable. However, I've struggled to find any work expanding this notion of separability for general nonassociative algebras. So: what is known about separability for arbitrary nonassociative algebras over a field? which properties continue to hold in the nonassociative case?